Are two convex solids with all corresponding shadows equal in area congruent?
By shadow we mean the orthogonal projection of a convex 3D body P onto a 2D plane, for example, the shadow on the xy-plane, with P above (z>0) that plane and the light at L=(0,0,+∞). P an be freely rotated as it hovers above the xy-plane and we consider the full set of shadows produced by a given convex body.

Let 2 convex 3D bodies P and Q be such that they hover over XY plane with their shadows having equal area. From this initial position and orientation of both bodies, let a same rotation transformation be applied to both P and Q keeping their centers of mass fixed. If the respective shadows are found to have equal areas for any same rotation done to both P and Q, can we conclude that P and Q congruent? If not, will they have equal volume/surface area? If none of these can be said in general, one can ask for bounds as to how much the volumes etc. of P and could differ.

Note: A variant can be asked with "equal perimeter" replacing "equal area" in the above (or “equal area and perimeter”…). One can also ask what happens if we consider only polyhedral solids.
An earlier question: Shadows and planar sections of polyhedra

Unfortunately not. Take any "Body of constant brightness" and compare it to a sphere and you get a counterexample.
About Note 1 curves of constant width give you counterexamples.
In general though, by Hadwiger's theorem, the convex sets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ you consider do have the same surface area, and if you considered equal perimeter as in Note 2 they'd have equal "1-dimensional size".
I do not know if asking for equal volume and area and perimeter of the projections would give you stronger results.
Wikipedia, surfaces of constant brightness
Nblog post about Hadwiger's theorem

Thanks for pointing this out. Hope the “equal perimeter” case in ‘note’ also gets resolved. Marking question as answered.
